# Angular-i18n is sometimes not loading the JSON-Translation-Files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, translation, angular-translate

I am using angular-i18n and sometimes the translation files doesn't get loaded. It is very curious because it is sometimes loaded and sometimes not, but I don't know why. Rarely only few files are loaded and not all translations. Is there any possibility only to show the views if all JSONS are loaded to 100%?

Comment: Are all of the files loading successfully according to your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @iblamefish When I open DevTools -> Spurces I can't find any JSONs in my folder structure

Comment: They aren't in Sources. They should be in Network/XHR